# dividing a string into separate columns pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

I have seen similar questions, but nothing that really matchs my problem. If I have a table of values such as:

```
value
a
b
b
c
```

I want to use pandas to add in columns to the table to show for example:

```
value a b
a 1 0 
b 0 1
c 0 0
```

I have tried the following:

```
df['a'] = 0

def string_count(indicator):
    if indicator == 'a':
        df['a'] == 1

df['a'].apply(string_count)
```

But this produces:

```
 0    None
 1    None
 2    None
 3    None
```

I would like to at least get to the point where the choices are hardcoded in (i.e I already know that a,b and c appear), but would even better if I could look set the column of strings and then insert a column for each unique string.

Am I approaching this the wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dummies = pd.get_dummies(df.value)

   a  b  c
0  1  0  0
1  0  1  0
2  0  1  0
3  0  0  1
```

If you only want to display unique occurrences, you can add:

```
dummies.index = df.value
dummies.drop_duplicates()

       a  b  c
value         
a      1  0  0
b      0  1  0
c      0  0  1
```

Alternatively:

```
df = df.join(pd.get_dummies(df.value))

  value  a  b  c
0     a  1  0  0
1     b  0  1  0
2     b  0  1  0
3     c  0  0  1
```

Where you could again `.drop_duplicates()` to only see unique entries from the `value` `column`.

Comment: How can I alter this so the columns appear with the main dataframe and not as a separate dataframe?